# How can I use these numbers?

Tags: arithmetic

How can you use the numbers 7 2 3 and 3 to equal 24? I have tried many different ways to make 24 but none have worked. I think I need a new brain to look at this from a different angle.

Comment: Please help. I'm stumped.

Comment: 3-2=1, 7+1=8, 8*3=24.

Comment: $(7\times2)+(3\times3)$ gets you close enough for government work.

Comment: Hehe...even closer: $$3^3-\frac72$$

Answer (score 2):

$(7 - 2 + 3) \times 3 = 24$ is one that works.

That's one that uses all four numbers from that collection, exactly once.  If you're not that restricted, there are lots of ways to do it which involve repeating numbers, or omitting numbers, from that collection.